# dropzone.js - how can I post dynamic div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to upload files with dropzone.js. 
My problem is that I have four dropzone upload containers on one page for different images.
How can I post the selected div to the post event?

```html
<div class='product_thumbs'>
  <form name="product_image_1" action="ajax/upload.php" class="dropzone">
    <div class="product_image image_1" id="image_1">
      <div class="fallback">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <input id="file_1" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_image image_2" id="image_2">
      <div class="fallback">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <input id="file_2" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_image image_3" id="image_3">
      <div class="fallback">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <input id="file_3" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_image image_4" id="image_4">
      <div class="fallback">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <input id="file_4" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image_1, .image_2, .image_3, .image_4").dropzone({
    url: "ajax/upload.php?product_id=" + $("#product_id").val() + "&image_number=" + $(this.element).data("id"), // Here I´ll post the id
      thumbnailWidth: 100,
      thumbnailHeight: 120,
      addRemoveLinks: false,
      previewTemplate: ""+
        "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">"+
        "<div class=\"dz-details\">"+
        //"<div class=\"dz-filename\"><span data-dz-name></span></div>"+
        //"<div class=\"dz-size\" data-dz-size></div>"+
        "<img data-dz-thumbnail />"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"dz-progress\"><span class=\"dz-upload\" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>"+
        "<div class=\"dz-error-message\"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>"+
        "</div>"
    });
});
```

How can I edit the URL after adding an image? I will post also the class or id of the selected file container...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

to get the id of current div

Comment: I think it is not so easy, because i need the id after the initialization^^. The dropzone  will be initialized after the page is loaded. If I choose an image the object is defined and upload the file. But I need to change the url before I upload it and it should be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

If you wish to simply post all of the input files give them all the same name e.g. `name="file[]"` the [] mean it's an array.

Comment: I know what an array is but I user the dropzone.js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and want to use it for more than one image uploader on one page. Also I want to add the image number (image_1, image_2, image_3 etc.) but I cant´t read the class/id of the selected file input.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to achieve, you're most likely going the wrong way about it. When you post images in an array, the first one in the HTML is the first one in the array. Therefore if you need/want to know which image is the first one, then the first one in the array will be image_1